# How to create a new integrated terminal in VSCode via PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm trying to streamline me typing `npm run dev` and `php artisan serve` for my Laravel projects.

I have a function working on my $PROFILE, but it only works on Windows Terminal (the app). How do I integrate this function to also work on VSCode's integrated terminal?

```
# warning, only use inside laravel folders with an npm run dev capability
function pand {
    wt --window 0 -p "Windows Powershell" -d "$pwd" powershell -noExit "npm run dev";
    php artisan serve;
}
```

Similar questions lead to usage of VSCode's Tasks feature. I would rather not have to result to using VSCode's Tasks because I usually use both VSCode's integrated terminal and Windows Terminal.

Comment: "_I would rather not have to result to using VSCode's Tasks because I usually use both VSCode's integrated terminal and Windows Terminal._" I'm confused. Is what you're asking for here not to basically open two integrated terminals doing different things? Or do you only want of the things to be done in the integrated terminal and another to be done with an external terminal?

Comment: If you decide you're okay with tasks, you can define a task to do each thing, and then define a [compound task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_compound-tasks) to run both at the same time. I don't think the exact thing you're looking for exists (running a commandline command to open a new integrated terminal in an existing VS Code window), though it's probably possible as a feature-request, which you can open an issue ticket to request (if you do, please comment here linking to it for posterity). Does that answer your question?